# wso2 is single logout partially working contd

Tags: wso2, logout, saml, opensaml, wso2-identity-server

How to send LogoutResponse from SP to IDP? The SP receives logoutRequest from IDP. I construct the Logout response and redirect it to IDP. But still the wso2 IS 5.0 sp1 console shows that 
Failed single logout response from .....status code Moved Temporarily

Referring the following 
[WSO2 IS Single Logout partially working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25643037/wso2-is-single-logout-partially-working)

it says to return the response instead of redirect. How should this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WSO2IS uses the back channel to send the logout request to other parties. You can just send a HTTP 200 OK as the logout response. You do not need to create proper logout response and send it..  Just want 200 OK..   You can find the code that send these logout request from [here](https://github.com/wso2/carbon-identity/blob/master/components/sso-saml/org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.saml/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/identity/sso/saml/logout/LogoutRequestSender.java). Then you can under stand following code which will check the returning status code

```
SAMLSSOUtil.isHttpSuccessStatusCode(statusCode)
```