# WSO2 Identity Server 5.3.0 Single Logout with simpleSAMLphp

Tags: wso2, simplesamlphp, wso2-identity-server

I have used WSO2 APP Manager to publish my web applications with Identity server 5.3.0 as the Identity Provider. I have configured SSO and SLO using three service providers. I'm using simpleSAMLphp with my web apps. SSO function works fine in my system but single logout is not working properly. I have configured this using the following document.
https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS500/SAML2+IdP+with+SimpleSAMLphp+Service+Provider

Can someone advice me regarding this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Please see [WSO2 IS Single Logout partially working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25643037/wso2-is-single-logout-partially-working)

Indeed WSO2 IS uses "backend channel" for SLO requests when logging out from multiple service providers (at least it was that way up to version 5.2.0), I don't believe it was changed/fixed in 5.3.0